# Unity LookAt, but instead rotate entire body towards direction in 3d space

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

Wasted many hours trying to figure out the rotations and many hours looking for answers, but wasn't able to find anything that fits my problem. I need to rotate an entire gameObject to a specific direction rather than rotating in y axis:

[image: Examples of wanted rotations]

1) How the object is currently rotated while given a direction inside Quaternion.LookRotation or by Atan2.
2,3) Examples of how it should rotate. The red ot simbolizes the pivot point from which the rotation happens

Not much code to show as there is not much to it besides gameObject transformations which are rotated and a direction in which to rotate gameObject.

As requested

```
[System.Serializable]
public class ToRotate
{
    //Object which will be rotated by the angle
    public GameObject gameObject;
    //Object last known position of this object. The object is rotated towards it's last global position
    private Vector3 lastPosition;

    //Initializes starting world position values to avoid a strange jump at the start.
    public void Init()
    {
        if (gameObject == null)
            return;

        lastPosition = gameObject.transform.position;
    }

    //Method which updates the rotation
    public void UpdateRotation()
    {
        //In order to avoid errors when object given is null.
        if (gameObject == null)
            return;
        //If the objects didn't move last frame, no point in recalculating and having a direction of 0,0,0
        if (lastPosition == gameObject.transform.position)
            return;

        //direction the rotation must face
        Vector3 direction = (lastPosition - gameObject.transform.position).normalized;

        /* Code that modifies the rotation angle is written here */

        //y angle
        float angle = Mathf.Rad2Deg * Mathf.Atan2(direction.x, direction.z);

        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, angle, 0);
        gameObject.transform.rotation = rotation;

        lastPosition = gameObject.transform.position;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please post the code that you are currently working on and provide with a minimal testable project to make it possible to work on it.

Comment: What direction is the camera pointing? It is unclear from the photo alone. Or better yet, can you provide the x,y, z components for the direction vector represented by the arrows pointing right in the image next to 1 and 2?

Comment: @Alsein code as requested and thank you.

Comment: @Ruzihm The picture is shown in x orthodox view, but the game itself uses isometric camera shoulder view. The example only has zy shown, but essentially what's required is the same thing, but in 3d xyz rotations. Sorry if that doesn't make sense. A good analogy would be to stack 100 elephants on their backs and rotate the earth in a way, so that the elephants would always be below the moon...

Comment: @Donatas the code+image was plenty illustrative :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want the object's *local down* to point in a calculated direction, while keeping the object's local *right* unchanged as possible, I would use [`Vector3.Cross`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Cross.html) to find the cross product of that *down* and *right* to determine the direction the object's local *forward* should face, then use [Quaternion.LookRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) to get the corresponding rotation:

```
//Method which updates the rotation
public void UpdateRotation()
{
    //In order to avoid errors when object given is null.
    if (gameObject == null)
        return;
    //If the objects didn't move last frame, no point in recalculating and having a direction of 0,0,0
    if (lastPosition == transform.position)
        return;

    //direction object's local down should face
    Vector3 downDir = (lastPosition - transform.position).normalized;

    // direction object's local right should face
    Vector3 rightDir = transform.right;

    // direction object's local forward should face
    Vector3 forwardDir = Vector3.Cross(downDir, rightDir);

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(forwardDir, -downDir);

    lastPosition = transform.position;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works like a charm. Shows how much I still have to learn :D.